# Convert std::vector<double> to Eigen::ArrayXd in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

how can I convert a vector to an eigen arrayxd in c++?

The only way I found involve doing:

```
Eigen::ArrayXd newEigen = Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero(oldVector.size());
```

and then making a loop to replace each element individually. Is there a better way?

I tried a loop. expecting simple way to copy the data, like:

```
Eigen::ArrayXd newEigen(oldVector.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably the most commonly asked question in the [eigen] tag, a surprising number of answers are not optimal. So here is the shortest, cleanest version:

```cpp
Eigen::ArrayXd newEigen = Eigen::ArrayXd::Map(
      oldVector.data(), static_cast<Eigen::Index>(oldVector.size()));
```

If you don't want to copy the data, an `Eigen::Map` borrows the data in the vector so you can access or change it in-place.

```cpp
Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXd> mapped(
      oldVector.data(), static_cast<Eigen::Index>(oldVector.size()));
```

`Eigen::Map` is to `Eigen::Array` what `std::string_view` is to `std::string` if that helps explaining.